# MySQL is not utilizing the index when the IN operator is used

Tags: mysql, execution-plan, index-tuning, mysql-8.0

I have a mysql 8 query like below.  the `ch_site_user` table is indexed on user_id, site_id, status.
Explain plan shows the correct index is used. But `usersite`.`site_id` IN (2315, 2316, 2324, 2323, 2320, 2322, 2326, 2319, 2318, 2317, 2325, 2345, 2346, 2330, 2347, 2348, 2350) came
in the Filter portion. Please correct the query so that the output can come without filter

Query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE  SELECT `usersite`.`id` AS `usersite.id` 
    FROM `cometchat_users` AS `user` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `ch_site_user` AS `usersite`
    ON  `user`.`userid` = `usersite`.`user_id`
    WHERE
    `user`.`tenantid` = 784 and 
    `usersite`.`site_id` IN (2315, 2316, 2324, 2323, 2320, 2322, 2326, 2319, 2318, 2317, 2325, 2345, 2346, 2330, 2347, 2348, 2350)
```

EXPLAIN output:

```
-> Limit: 200 row(s)  (cost=348966 rows=200) (actual time=0.0507..0.222 rows=200 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=348966 rows=237993) (actual time=0.0499..0.211 rows=200 loops=1)
        -> Covering index lookup on user using X_cu_tenantid (tenantid=784)  (cost=75398 rows=752098) (actual time=0.0287..0.0344 rows=18 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (usersite.site_id in (2315,2316,2324,2323,2320,2322,2326,2319,2318,2317,2325,2345,2346,2330,2347,2348,2350))  (cost=0.25 rows=0.316) (actual time=0.00373..0.00903 rows=11.1 loops=18)
            -> Covering index lookup on usersite using U_csu_user_site_status (user_id=`user`.userid)  (cost=0.25 rows=1.14) (actual time=0.0034..0.0078 rows=11.8 loops=18)
```

Comment: *the ch_site_user table is indexed on user_id, site_id, status* Show this as complete CREATE TABLE script. *came in the Filter portion* Too many values (above ~10). *correct the query so that the output can come without filter* 1) Create composite index `usersite (user_id, site_id)`. 2) Force its usage if needed. 3) Maybe convert the list to rowset.

Answer (score 1):

"Danger, Will Robinson!"
Make sure this join is behaving the way you *think* it is.

Putting WHERE conditions on the "right" table in a LET OUTER JOIN can *collapse* the
join's 'OUTER'ness, reducing it an **INNER** join.

For such cases, put the conditions on the "right" table into the join's "on" clause, *instead of* the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT usersite.id AS usersite.id 
FROM cometchat_users AS user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ch_site_user AS usersite
   ON user.userid = usersite.user_id
  AND usersite.site_id IN (2315, 2316, 2324, 2323, 2320, 2322, 2326, 2319, 2318, 2317, 2325, 2345, 2346, 2330, 2347, 2348, 2350) 
WHERE user.tenantid = 784 
...
```

Regards,   Phill W.

Comment: The point is -- For `LEFT`, placement of conditions (`ON` vs `WHERE`) matters.  For `INNER JOIN` (aka `JOIN`), the query results will be the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `LEFT JOIN` is really `JOIN`, the Optimizer gets to choose which table to start with.  The following "composite" indexes will let it pick either direction and make a rational decision if which is best.

```
usersite:  INDEX(site_id, user_id, id)
usersite:  INDEX(user_id, site_id, id)
user:  INDEX(tenantid, userid)
```

Those are also "covering", which gives an extra boost in performance.

In general, `IN` optimizes somewhere between `=` and a "range".

When asking performance questions, be sure to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.